# Specific Javascript function giving an uncaught type error, others work normally

Tags: javascript, html

I have a bunch of javascript that checks the contents of certain fields and returns false if they are empty or do not meet specific conditions. Here is an example of a working function.

```
if(!medicalform.surname.value.length){
valid=false;
 document.getElementById('surname-required').style.display = "inline-block";
 document.getElementById('surname').focus();
}
```

So I have this part of my javascript:

```
if (!medicalform.dob.value.length) {
valid=false;
document.getElementById('dob-required').style.display = "inline-block";
document.getElementById('dob').focus();
}

if (!medicalform.cob.value.length) {
valid=false;
document.getElementById('cob-required').style.display = "inline-block";
document.getElementById('cob').focus();
}
```

that read the length of the date field and the country field respectively, and if they do not have a length, they will change the variable valid to false, highlight and reveal a span message telling the person completing the form to fill it in, and return false to the form being fully filled in.

However, when running the script, it says

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`

**I have attached the dob and cob parts of my html respectively.**

Date of Birth: `<input type="date" id="dob" name="dob" min="1900-01-01">
<span class="error-messages" id="dob-required"> Please enter your date of birth. </span>`

Country of Birth: 
`<select name="country" id="cob" name="cob" onChange="dropDownList(this);"> <span class="error-messages" id="cob-requried"> Please enter your country of birth </span>`

What could be going wrong? The error points to the style.display of the dob javascript.

Comment: Can you tell us when and how are these validations fired?

Comment: Well I have the javascript run when I press the submit button, as the purpose all my functions is to ensure key fields are not only filled in but also within specific constraints. When I press the Submit button, my answers are run through the series of functions, and if they do not meet then the submission process is aborted and I am able to go back and edit my answers.

Comment: However, in this case when I press Submit, it accepts the 'responses' even though I have quite plainly not answered a single field. Upon checking the console, it seemed the dob function threw up an error when trying to apply a style to null. Being a complete newbie to Javascript, I decided to see wtf was happening.

Comment: Thankyou for the quick responses but this is very time limited :') I have to move on to other parts of the assignment. Thankyou for the offers but this thing is due in hour and I've been awake for almost 35 hours now